# Using microservices architecture in spring

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm building a project which based on microservices architecture in spring boot.The project was divided multiple modules and I used maven dependency management.

Now I want to use services from one module in other module. I have many spring applications. For example, I have 2 application which is named A and B. I want to use classes from A in B and classes of B in A. In this case I used maven dependencies but it is not completely way to using services in one another because I faced with circular dependency.

What should do to use for solve this problem?

Comment: you need to duplicate classes i.e each service will have its own data(classses) for using between them.

Comment: I think this way is needless, because duplicate codes in every application is not useful

Comment: Also, cyclic dependencies between 2 services mean in the end, that it's a bad design and they should be combined in one application.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea to share classes between microservices, if you want to replace microservice A, you'll have to adapt Microservice B. 
Every Service must implement its own data classes which holds the fields which are needed for the service.

MicroService A and MicroService B both can contain a class Foo but this classes can be different by its fields. Perhaps both contain the field 'id' and 'name' but only Microservice A also needs a field 'date' to do his work.

Comment: Yes I agree with you

Answer (score 1):

If you have classes that need to be in some of your `Microservices`, i think it's better to make a `shared library` and put your shared classes in that, then use your `shared library` in your `Microservices`.

Actually i think it's a good idea to put classes that need to be in most of your `Microservices` in a `shared library` and use that library. But should be careful, because it may comes to `tight coupling` which isn't a good thing in `Microservices Architecture`.

Personally i think some `Configuration` classes and some `Event models` that most of your `Microservices` use are good candidates. But i don't think sharing your `Service` classes between your `Microservices` are a good idea. Instead they should use each other's services as they are completely independent and are using external services.

Answer (score 0):

create one common entity application and add that entity application as a dependency. For example assume you have stored user data in micorservice1(MC1) and need this class(User) in other microservices(like MC2, MC3,MC4, and so  on) then you can create one entity application like util and add this dependency in required microservices.

Comment: Ok If I do that, It will be ok but If I want to use whole application in another application What I do?

Comment: What about Eureka server of spring ?

Comment: it's not an application , just common entity without pom, main.... So its not an application

Comment: Eureka server is only used for registry and discovery purpose

Comment: Ok So you want to say not the most optimal way to do it which you mentioned way?